# View all the text in a column in R

Tags: r, rstudio

I have a character variable with long text. I can not see the full text of this variable (as shown in the image) in R Studio. Is there a way to display it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like there is not.

Looking at the rstudio website I found the following:

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/214222927-Resize-columns-of-the-data-viewer

Comment: I understand from the comment that they do not have the capability yet. Thanks for this will accept it as an answer that basically say 'there is no way to do it'

Comment: Broken URL. The bad side of only-url answers.

Answer (score 2):

You could save it as a .csv and then view the entire column that way.

```
    write.csv(MyData, file = "MyData.csv")
```

Not sure if this is the best way, but it's my go-to when I have long strings of data in one column.

Comment: Yes, done that, but would have liked to be able to read it in R

Comment: Here's a link to the R discussion leading to my second answer:

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/205175388-Using-the-Data-Viewer

Answer (score 1):

I just found an newer version of R that was created to expand columns. Here's the link to it:

https://dailies.rstudio.com/

You should be able to click and drag the column to whatever width you want.